# Pass variable to RunWorkerCompleted() after DoWork() is done

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, backgroundworker

I am using VS 2015 winform background workers to do some tasks.

I have `DoWork()` method that uses `List<string> myList`, and it removes each entry in the list once certain process is complete. My goal is to let users know which entry in `myList` was not processed (since it deletes an entry after every process, whatever is left in the end is the one that is NOT processed). To do so, I was going to pass the `myList` variable to `RunWorkerCompleted()`, but not only do I not know how to do this, I am not even sure if this is the best way of doing it.

Are there better ways to let users know which entry in `myList` was not processed, and if not, how would I pass a variable from DoWork() to RunWorkerCompleted()?

Current RunWorkerCompleted() method:

```
private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
}
```

Basically, I want the MessageBox to display which entries are not processed when it's done running a task

Comment: any reason not to use async/await instead of background workers as that is the recommended approach?

Comment: Im a beginner user so I don't exactly know the difference, but i thought async was for Web-based application. Mine is offline winform (like no network connection, not using server)

Comment: @djskj189 `async` is a useful tool for any application dealing with an asynchronous operation.  If you have an asynchronous operation, you can use it.

Comment: @PeterBons The background worker is a means to have UI feedback while you do background works. You can't (easily) do that with async and await

Comment: @Emad this is my case. It constantly updates UI during the process to report what's happening

Comment: @Emad You absolutely *can* do that without using a BGW.  You can simply use a `Progress` instance.

Comment: @djskj189 There are other ways to that like what Servy is saying but what you do is a perfectly standard way to do it. If you managed to pull it off with what I said just mark the answer if you want more explanation I can help.

Comment: @Emand Well, please read this msnd documentation about the async/await vs backgroundworker as backgroundmaterial. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx#Threads

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the result of the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result(v=vs.110).aspx)

OK for some people who just don't want to read, use this

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Do your work
    e.Result = mylist;
}

private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        ShowResult(e.Result as List<string>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a code example.  Links die, but people will still be coming here for answers.

Comment: How would it know which "result" is myList variable? It also uses other variables and it's not like it has a return type

Comment: @Archer The answer isn't dependant on the link.

Comment: @djskj189 The result is whatever you pass it in as.  If you pass in a list, the result gets a list.  If you pass in something else, it gets something else.

Comment: @Servy without at least a basic example, this is not an answer.

Comment: @Archer That's just false.  Explaining how someone can solve their problem is more than sufficient in an answer.  You don't need to actually give them the code for it.  I've posted many hundreds of answers here that don't contain any code, and merely explain how the question can be resolved.  It's often the *superior* answer to someone who just gives someone code to copy-paste without understanding.

Comment: That's better.  Now it's not just a statement and a link.  @Servy There will always be instances where code is not relevant, but saying "pass it as a parameter - here's a link" is not an answer.  Respond if you wish, but I'm not arguing over this and will not respond as it's irrelevant now that the poster has done the correct thing.

Comment: @Archer I'm a programmer and here is a link (to MSDN) is all I would ever need

Comment: @Archer The answer was *never* just a link.  The link could have never been included in the post and it would have still been an answer.  Adding a link to the end of an answer doesn't make it stop being an answer.

Comment: @Archer Yes, by all means, congratulate  yourself into bullying someone into destroying a good teachable moment for someone who had an opportunity to actually learn how to solve a problem, and how just has code to copy paste without understanding, all because you don't even understand the site's own guidelines are for what is Not An Answer and think that adding a link to the end of an answer somehow makes it stop being an answer.

Comment: Great answer, didn't realise background workers implemented all you need to pass variables through! +1